# Would this function for checking if a BST(Binary Search Tree ) Is valid work Python

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

So this is my code below, my thought process is that if the smallest value in the tree is less than the root and the largest value in the tree is greater than the root it should check if the BST is valid

```
    def min(self):
       while self.left:
           self.root = self.left
    return self.root

    def max(self):
        while self.right:
            self.root = self.right
    return self.value

    def valid(self):
        min = min(self.left)
        max = max(self.right)

        if self.root > min and self.root < max:
            return True
```

Comment: What makes you think it would not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reuse the names `min` and `max`.  They already refer to built-in functions.

Your `min` and `max` functions change the tree, by changing `self.root`.

You should be validating that the values of the left and right child nodes are correct relative to the parent node, then validating that each of the BSTs rooted at those child nodes is itself valid.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def valid(self):
        if self.left and self.left.value > self.value:
            return False
        if self.right and self.right.value < self.value:
            return False
        return all(node.valid() for node in (self.left, self.right) if node)
```